# Website footer in absolute not staying at bottom when page expands

Tags: html, css

I have a footer at the bottom of my page. When I load the page and there's no scroll bar (full screen, no y-overflow), the footer sits snugly at the bottom of the page. My issue is that when I add content which expands the height of my page (requiring a scrollbar), the footer stays in the same place whilst my content moves down and expands the page. I do not intend to use `position:fixed`, because I only want the user to see the footer once scrolling all the way down to the bottom of the page. Here is the relevant HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div id="textbox" style="top:46px;left:45px;margin-right:33px;">ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.</div>

<div id="footer"><p>This is the footer.</p></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#textbox {
position:relative;
background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
padding:10px;
font-family:arial;
z-index:-1;
box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(000,000,000,1);
border-radius:10px;
line-height:25px;
}


#footer {
background-color:white;
width:50000px;
height:75px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
color:black;
font-family:arial;
border:0px;
margin:0px
}
```

As you can see, I though using position:absolute and seeting left and bottom to 0px would do the job, but this doesn't work when I scroll down because the footer stays stationary. As mentioned, fixed is not an option and surely there is a way around this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you please change the width: 50000px to width: 100%; let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: @wuno Please read my latest comment, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for you:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbNWgg

I added a container DIV `#container1`. The essential/changed parts of the CSS are:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#container1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

When there is a lot of text (which I inserted), the footer is below the textblock. If you erase major parts of the text, you'll see that the footer remains at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

What Will You need here , is to use postion:relative to footer buttom will be 0 ,

```css
#textbox {
background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
padding:10px;
font-family:arial;
z-index:-1;
box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(000,000,000,1);
border-radius:10px;
line-height:25px;
}


#footer {
background-color:white;
width:50000px;
height:75px;
position:relative;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
color:black;
font-family:arial;
border:0px;
margin:0px
}
```

```html
<div id="textbox">
text Here text here
</div> 
<div id="textbox">
text Here text here
</div> 
<div id="textbox">
text Here text here
</div> 
<div id="textbox">
text Here text here
</div> 

<div id="footer"><p>This is the footer.</p></div>
```

Comment: This does not at all work, and only displaces my footer even more twoards the top.

Comment: Ya you are doing it right with position absolute. Relative will not fix this. Please tell me what browser your using.

Comment: position relative fix the problem , please try it ,

Answer (score 0):

Let me know whether this is what you want.
Have a wrapper class for this html and assign position relative to that.

```
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:75px;
}
#textbox {
background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
padding:10px;
font-family:arial;
z-index:-1;
box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(000,000,000,1);
border-radius:10px;
line-height:25px;
display:block;
}


#footer {
background-color:white;
width:50000px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
color:black;
font-family:arial;
border:0px;
margin:0px;
display:block;

height:75px;
}
```

Get the height of footer and explicitly declare the value and assiign the same value to the padding bottom of the wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Using `relative` position on the `footer` and adding a `margin-bottom` on `#textbox` which is the size of your footer will work (if I understand correctly what you wants)

```
#textbox {
position:relative;
background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
padding:10px;
font-family:arial;
z-index:-1;
box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(000,000,000,1);
border-radius:10px;
line-height:25px;
margin-bottom: 75px; 
}


#footer {
background-color:white;
width:100%;
height:75px;

position:relative;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
color:black;
font-family:arial;
border:0px;
margin:0px
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcve3tu5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you're looking for:

```css
body, html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.content{
  padding-bottom:75px;
}
#textbox {
  position:relative;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  padding:10px;
  font-family:arial;
  box-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(000,000,000,1);
  border-radius:10px;
  line-height:25px;
}


#footer {
background-color:white;
width:100%;
height:75px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
color:black;
font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">

  <div id="textbox">ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br>ASSUME THERE IS A LOT OF TEXT HERE, CAUSING PAGE TO OVERFLOW DOWNWARDS.<br></div>
</div>
  <div id="footer"><p>This is the footer.</p></div>

</div>
```